# Porting C# .net to run on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, winforms, porting

I was looking through this http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/ to see if I could port it but it seems MoMA is no longer updated. Is there something newer to check with?

My program is fairly simple, it however uses a WebBrowser control and I think that might be my issue with porting it. Is there any support for WebBrowser in OSX? Is there a good alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Consider looking into [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)

Comment: That guide itself is no longer a valid article. Mono WinForms is incomplete, and it also does not support 64 bit. You should switch to Xamarin.Mac, and use Cocoa to design a true Mac app, and then share whatever code you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try with first installing Visual Studio on Mac (as mentioned in comment). Then create a fresh `.NetStandard` or `.NetCore` project and transfer all your files to this new one. The start compiling and resolve any porting errors you get.